# List total number of users that are authors

Tags: user-roles, list-authors, users

### Question

I want to display total number of Authors and total number of subscribers on the blog but exclude the admin in this way:

***56*** Authors so far

***15*** Subscribers so far

### Code that is close to what I need :)

I have this code and it displays the total number of everybody that is registered. I need it to display authors and subscriber roles separately. Please help :)

```
<?php $users = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM $wpdb->users");
echo $users." members so far"; ?>
```

## Answer updated:

Thank You @JanBeck This code generates the number of authors

```
echo count( get_users( array( 'role' => 'author' ) ) )
```

Answer (score 3):

[`count_users()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/count_users) should give you an array of all the required user counts.

You can use it like this.

```
$user_counts = count_users();

$authors = $user_counts['avail_roles']['author'];    //Get the author count
$subscribers = $user_counts['avail_roles']['subscriber'];    //Get the subscriber count

echo $authors. ' Authors so far';
echo $subscribers. ' Subscribers so far';
```

Comment: Can You please give me the working examples for counting authors and counting subscribers for I am not that good in coding :) Thank You so very much!

Comment: @jimilesku Please always search in Codex (helps you learning), when someone only posts a Template Tag. Thanks.

Comment: @kaiser I am doing my best, thank YOu for the input :) Learning every day something new :)

Comment: I think this is the correct answer. Using **WP_User_Query** class is more expensive, as it returns all the users. On the other hand, **get_users()** only returns the stats your requested in your question.

Answer (score 2):

### The WP_User_Query class

There's the [`WP_User_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query) for exactly that. This class is an extension for the cores base `wpdb` class. The counting will therefore be saved inside the `global $wpdb;` object and is easy accessible.

```
global $wpdb;
$author_search = new WP_User_Query( array( 'role' => 'author' ) );
$author_list   = $author_search->get_results();
$author_count  = $wpdb->num_rows;
```

Comment: Where do I place the code? I placed it in footer and it returned: FATAL ERROR: CALL TO A MEMBER FUNCTION GET_RESULTS() ON A NON-OBJECT IN... Please help :)

Comment: See edit. Forgot to rename a var.

Comment: Answer is ok but this one is a bit shorter: `count( get_users( array( 'role' => 'author' ) ) )`

Comment: @JanBeck I placed the echo before the code You wrote and it works perfectly :) Thank You so much!

Comment: Then add it as answer - will get a +1 from me. I tend to use classes for answer, when they're considered _also_ a public API (WP mixes there a lot), as you can show more possibilities.

Comment: @kaiser using classes is perfectly fine but I think it tends to confuse novices. At least it did to me back when I started :)

Answer (score 1):

```
echo count( get_users( array( 'role' => 'author' ) ) )
```

Answer (score -1):

you can try this attracts all members

```
  $users = get_users();

     foreach ($users as $get_users) {
        echo $get_users->display_name . '<br>';
     }
```

Comment: The question is about counting different types of users though.