# Total number of authors with more than one post

Tags: users

```
<?php 
$users = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM $wpdb->users");
echo '(', count( get_users( array( 'role' => 'author' ) ) ); echo ')' 
?>
```

[code by Jan Beck](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/60368/73)

I need to know what is my best option for displaying the total number of authors who have at least posted and/or published something on my blog.

Currently the code is counting all the authors even if they haven't posted anything. Please let me know if there is a simple solution to this. I have looked throughout the wordpress codex and have not found a solution to this yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that `wp_list_authors` will do what you want, sort of. You could run the function with the `echo` parameter false and count the results.

```
$authors = wp_list_authors(
  array(
    'echo'=>false,
    'html'=>false
  )
);
echo var_dump($authors);
echo count (explode(',',$authors));
```

Or, alternately, and perhaps less profligately, steal that function's `SQL`.

```
$authors = $wpdb->get_results(
  "SELECT DISTINCT post_author, COUNT(ID) AS count 
  FROM $wpdb->posts 
  WHERE post_type = 'post' 
  AND " . get_private_posts_cap_sql( 'post' ) . " 
  GROUP BY post_author"
);
var_dump($authors); 
echo count($authors);
```

Those are slightly different in that the first ignores the admin user by default, but there is a parameter to change that.

Comment: These are close I can feel it.

But I just need the total count eg lets say i have 38 authors but only 28 have posted something i want the count to = 28 not 38... Let me know if that helps. I was thinking a $user_count with hide_empty => true or something to this extent.

Comment: Man Im not the brightest bulb thats for sure I took the first code and it worked 

$authors = wp_list_authors(
  array(
    'echo'=>false,
    'html'=>false
  )
);

echo '(', count (explode(',',$authors));echo ')'

You ROCK - s_ha_dum Thank you so much saved my but

Comment: @Joe : if this solved the problem please select it as the "accepted" solution.