# Get total number of authors on the site

Tags: users

How do I get total number of Authors on the site?

This shows summery of users on the site but I just want to get number of Authors.

```
<?php
$result = count_users();
echo 'There are ', $result['total_users'], ' total users';
foreach($result['avail_roles'] as $role => $count)
    echo ', ', $count, ' are ', $role, 's';
echo '.';
?>
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/count_users

Comment: [see first question in related column](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/60327/list-total-number-of-users-that-are-authors?rq=1) -->

Comment: Thank you! the answer with `count_users();` works for me.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [`WP_User_Query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query) class, like the example below. Each code line have an small description, that you understand, what we do.

```
// Get all users with role Author.
$user_query = new WP_User_Query( array( 'role' => 'Author' ) );
// Get the total number of users for the current query. I use (int) only for sanitize.
$users_count = (int) $user_query->get_total();
// Echo a string and the value
echo 'So much authors: ' . $users_count;
```

Alternative you can also use the function [`get_users()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users). But is only a wrapper for the query and have much more fields in the result.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want one field and/or a count, you can use [get_users()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users). Restricting the fields returned makes for a fast query.

```
$users_count = count( get_users( array( 'fields' => array( 'ID' ), 'role' => 'author' ) ) );
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want authors count

```
 <?php
$result = count_users();
echo count( get_users( array( 'role' => 'author' ) ) );
?>
```

Comment: Why do you waste time for `count_users()` if you never use it?

Comment: @fuxia - Is `count( get_users( array( 'role' => 'author' ) ) )` faster performing than `count_users()`?

Comment: @Motivated Probably not, but `count_users()` doesn't allow a limitation for a certain role.

Comment: @fuxia, do you mean like `$user_counts['avail_roles']['author']` or not allowing a limit as to the count which could result in a performance hit?

Comment: @Motivated The array access comes after the query. If you have many users, you want to fetch only the data you really need, not all of them.

Comment: @fuxia, that makes sense but how is that different to `get_users`?

Answer (score 0):

The WP class [`WP_User_Query`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_user_query/) is inefficient if all you want is a count. The constructor runs [`query()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_user_query/query/) producing an unnecessary call to `users` table, then a subsequent call with `SELECT FOUND_ROWS()`.

After reviewing the wp core code we implement this filter.

```php
add_filter('users_pre_query', function($result, WP_User_Query $user_query) {

   global $wpdb;
   $user_count = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(1) {$user_query->query_from} {$user_query->query_where}");
   if(empty($wpdb->last_error)) $user_query->total_users = (int)$user_count;

   return false;
}, 10, 2);
```

The filter prevents local `results` from running and correctly sets `total_users` for use of:

```php
$user_query = new WP_User_Query();
$user_query->get_total();
```

You'll want to remove the filter after instantiating.