# Get number of authors

Tags: wp-query

I want to get the number of authors.
I saw [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/203639/get-total-number-of-authors-on-the-site) and moved (all).

I got number 0 or 1 but real is 3.

What should I do?

Comment: Welcome to WPSE! You need to be more specific. The more detail in your question, the more detailed the answers will be. Editing your question to include the code that you applied would be a good start.

Answer (score 1):

This reply was pretty low on the list, on the article you referred to; but it will do the job:

```
$users_count = count(get_users(array('fields'=>array('ID'),'role'=>'author')));
```

Originally posted [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/203639/get-total-number-of-authors-on-the-site#answer-203649), buy [shanebp](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/16575/shanebp)